# How to collect data table result in string array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, linq

I have a table with column Email. It contains some email address. I want get those details into string array. Help me to find a proper solution. Thank you.

Code:

```
 alertDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_AutoAssignCadTeamTableAdapter EM;
 EM = new alertDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_AutoAssignCadTeamTableAdapter();
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt = EM.GetEmpMail();
```

dt getting email address.

**EDIT:** Update from OP's post to the Answer section

Now I am getting another error. The Error is : `"The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address."`

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

  alertDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_AutoAssignCadTeamTableAdapter EM;
  EM = new alertDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_AutoAssignCadTeamTableAdapter();
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt = EM.GetEmpMail();

  string[] emails = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<String>("Email")).ToArray();

  MailMessage loginInfo = new MailMessage();
  loginInfo.To.Add(emails.ToString()); // error popup here.
  loginInfo.From = new MailAddress("fromID@gmail.com");
  loginInfo.Subject = "Hai";

  loginInfo.Body = "Hai";
  loginInfo.IsBodyHtml = true;
  SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
  smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
  smtp.Port = 587;
  smtp.EnableSsl = true;
  smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("fromID@gmail.com", "***");
  smtp.Send(loginInfo);

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add emails with a loop and send.

try this

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        alertDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_AutoAssignCadTeamTableAdapter EM;
        EM = new alertDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_AutoAssignCadTeamTableAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = EM.GetEmpMail();

        string[] emails = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<String>("Email")).ToArray();

        MailMessage loginInfo = new MailMessage();
        foreach (var email in emails)
        {
            loginInfo.To.Add(email);
        }

        loginInfo.From = new MailAddress("fromID@gmail.com");
        loginInfo.Subject = "Hai";

        loginInfo.Body = "Hai";
        loginInfo.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("fromID@gmail.com", "***");
        smtp.Send(loginInfo);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ for your purpose:

```
dt = EM.GetEmpMail();

string[] emails = dt.AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(x=>x.Field<String>("Email"))
                    .ToArray();
```

Initially, we get a sequence of the rows of the datatable, using the `DataTable`'s extension method called `AsEnumerable`. The we select from the sequence of rows we get the value of the column with name Email.

Comment: Even if the table has only one column your query does not return that column. So the result is a `DataRow[]` because `x` is a `DataRow`.

Comment: No, there is more than one column. I am selecting only email column.

Answer (score 1):

So you want all emails as `String[]`? You can use `Linq-To-DataTable`. Use [`DataRow.Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field(v=vs.90).aspx) to select only the email-column.

```
string[] emails = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<String>("Email")).ToArray();
```